# Using for loops to create multiple lists

Tags: python, list, for-loop

Currently I have a function.

```
def create1(n): 

    output = []
    for i in range(n):
        output.append(int(i)+1)
    return output
```

It returns [1,2,3] whenever enter create(3). However, I want it to return [[1],[1,2],[1,2,3]]. 
I know there's a problem with something in my for loop but I can't figure it out.

Comment: [Are you asking almost the same question each time ?](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3000645/user3000645)

Answer (score 4):

Use `range()` to create lists of numbers quickly:

```
def create1(n): 
    output = []
    for i in range(n):
       output.append(range(1, i + 2))
    return output
```

or, using a list comprehension:

```
def create1(n): 
    return [range(1, i + 2) for i in range(n)]
```

If you are using Python 3, turn the iterator returned by `range()` into a list first:

```
for i in range(n):
   output.append(list(range(1, i + 2)))
```

Quick demo:

```
>>> def create1(n): 
...     return [range(1, i + 2) for i in range(n)]
... 
>>> create1(3)
[[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Answer (score 3):

This works in Python 2 and Python 3:

```
>>> def create1(n):
...   return [list(range(1,i+1)) for i in range(1,n+1)]
...
>>> create1(5)
[[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

Answer (score 0):

What you really want is a list appended at every stage. So try this

```
def create1(n): 
    output = []
    for i in range(n):
        output.append(range(1,i+2)) # append a list, not a number.
    return output
```

`range(n)` gives you a list of integers from 0 to n-1. So, at each stage (at each i), you're appending to the output a list from 0 to i+1.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def create(n):
    output = []
    for i in range(n):
        output.append(range(1,i+2))
    return output


print create(3)
```